# Activity with fragments crashes like if it were nested fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I guess everybody knows the project that is created when you choose "master detail flow" when creating your project in eclipse. [image]

Theres layouts for the left side, for the right side and a two_pane layout with a fragment and a Framelayout as a fragment container. This works fine.

Now I have a 'main' activity A with a viewpager, fragments etc., and i call the activity from a fragment with the Callback. From that activity A I start a new activity B. That activity B is set up exactly like that example activity from eclipse that I just talked about.

Now I have the problem that the app crashes with

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8105): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #57: Duplicate id 0x7f080024, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for FragmentNumber3
```

When I replace the fragment in the two_pane layout with another framelayout, it doesn't crash. 
This problem is typical for nested fragments, but I don't have nested fragments here, right? I have an activity B that, at that point, doesn't have anything to do with my activity A.

What's the problem here?

Edit: This is my Activity B:

public class SucheActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        SearchboxFragment.SearchboxListener {

```
private boolean mTwoPane;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.searchbox);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    if (findViewById(R.id.searchresult_container) != null) {

        mTwoPane = true;
    }
}
}
```

And thats the two_pane layout for the activity, the searchbox should be left, the searchresults right:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/searchbox_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.layouttest.SearchboxFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchresult_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Heres the SearchboxFragment class:

```
public class SearchboxFragment extends Fragment {

SearchboxListener mCallback;
View v;

public interface SearchboxListener {
    public void onSearchStarted();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.searchbox, container, false);


    return v;
}
}
```

The searchresultfragment:

```
public class SearchResultFragment extends Fragment {


public SearchResultFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.searchresult, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

}

}
```

And the refs.xml in res/values-large:

```
<resources>

    <item name="searchbox" type="layout">@layout/haussuche_twopane</item>

</resources>
```

Comment: are you sure there arent 2 veiws with same id?

Comment: I think so yes. I added some code.

Comment: from the error it seems like two views have same id and is collapsing with each other probably trying to access 1st activitys view which is not available just make sure all id's are unique

Comment: Added some code now, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is what I found out:

I cant set the layout of my Activity to searchbox.xml (and have it alias'd in refs.xml with two_pane.xml) AND set the Layout of SearchboxFragment to searchbox.xml.

I thought that searchbox.xml was never shown by the Activity in two-pane-mode, I could safely set it elsewhere, but that's wrong.

What I did was copy that layout and use a searchbox_onepane.xml and searchbox_twopane.xml.